# Qual a diferença entre "is null" e "== null" em C#?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, operadores, estilo-de-codificação, null

Em C# eu posso verificar se `object? foo` é nulo com:

```
foo == null
```

E também

```
foo is null
```

Ambos são verdadeiros se `foo` é nulo.

Existe alguma diferença semântica entre cada um?

Comment: [Demonstração.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e73udg)

Comment: Não sei muito sobre C#, mas acho que o `is` é para verificar se um objeto é do mesmo tipo de outro objeto. Acho que ele seria o equivalente do `instanceof` do JavaScript.

Comment: @CmteCardeal posso usar o is para comparar com expressões e valores também, além de tipos.

Comment: Quando eu fiz essa pergunta no SOen ela teve votos para fechar, negativos e comentários ruins. Depois tudo mudou, os comentários negativos foram apagados, os negativos retirados e se tornou uma das perguntas mais votadas de C# por lá. EU tenho feito parzinhos aqui com esse mesmo tipo de conteúdo que ajuda as pessoas aprenderem a usar melhor a linguagem. Em geral está sendo bem recebido, ainda que pouco porque quase ninguém vota mais. Tem sempre um que acha ruim e negativa esse tip ode pergunta. Ainda bem que nesta não (ainda, espero que continue assim).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em um primeiro momento não tem diferença alguma e assim deveria ocorrer sempre em condições normais. Ambos dão o mesmo resultado, e a forma de executar é a mesma, não tem diferença de performance, gera o mesmo CIL.

A não ser que o operador `==` seja descrito no objeto que está sendo comparado. Aí a implementação desse operador passa valer e pode não só ter um com promisso diferente de execução, mas pode até dar um resultado diferente.

Deveria dar? Em hipótese alguma, mas pode. Não há impedimento técnico.

O `is` não pode ser sobrecarregado e a execução é sempre a mesma em qualquer situação, o `==` pode ser sobrecarregado.

Em versão antiga do compilador, provavelmente por *bug*, até tinha uma diferença de execução, apesar de dar o mesmo resultado, mas isso foi resolvido em versões posteriores e geram o mesmo código.

[Já chegaram testar isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40676671/221800):

```
using System;
public class C {
    bool M1(object x) => x is null;
    bool M2(object x) => x == null;
}
```

[Veja no **ShapLab** como o código fica igual](https://sharplab.io/#b:master/f:%3Eilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmAge06JgFkAjAApOBAFapSyGAA8AlDAC8APlkwwdCMCJEcASC49+AJhHjJ0+UtUylimFp04AvkA==).

E com o uso de *overload*:

```
using System;

public class C {
    bool M1(C x) => x is null;
    bool M2(C x) => x == null;
    
    int x;
    public C(int x){this.x=x;}
    public static bool operator== (C o1, C o2) => o1.x == o2.x;
    public static bool operator!= (C o1, C o2)=> o1.x != o2.x;
    public override bool Equals(object o2) => ((C)o2).x == x;
    public override int GetHashCode() => x.GetHashCode();
}
```

[Veja no **ShapLab** como o código fica diferente](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgqcBmIgJgIGECBvKgrg4Ae14wEAssQAUrAB4BKAgF4AfAQkE0UAgDsArhgwVKASD4DhDcUpkKlc2Ru27O3B1zTqYSvdyL1mol2+lsMAAWqgB0ErISpAC+Tl5ExABsPPyCvAAOiBAwvAiyNma8xEgsBLwMFopF4dZlDOEe3HQJyUZpmQjZuQCEBaxFJf0VltXKvXUNcc28AG6ICGgAJnApxgCiAI6aEBhQorzAAFZwAMZu5ZUEouJSFzX57lP0s/NLK34EAOJwMAAS0EFmLxlqJLhJQt8/gCgSCpHpokA==), e ele chama o método em vez de usar a instrução simples.

Lá também vemos que tem diferença quando usa *generics*.

```
bool IsNull<T>(T item) => item is null; // Compile error: CS0403
bool IsNull<T>(T item) => item == null;
bool IsNull<T>(T item) where T : class => item is null;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/ComparingNullIsEqual.cs).

O `is` só funciona com classes, o `==` funciona com qualquer tipo. De qualquer forma deveria dar o mesmo resultado e se você não fizer estrepolia na sua classe dará.

Finalmente, há uma diferença de no desenvolvimento já que o `is` pega o erro em compilação *para tipos não anuláveis*, já que eles nunca podem ser nulos. O `==` não consegue fazer isso e terá que executar para dar o resultado, que certamente será `false` se não fez as tais estrepolias, então ele é menos eficiente e menos seguro.

Comment: `item` nunca será `null` se `T` for uma estrutura, correto? Além disso, se sobrecarregar o operador `==`, ainda consigo usar o `is` no mesmo objeto?

Comment: Sim, e sim, o `==` é independente do `is`.